# Dividing tied RANKs using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

Still getting the hang of interpreting the `MDX` documentation on `MSDN`. So for the [`RANK` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx) it has the following:

> If a numeric expression is specified, the Rank function determines the
>   one-based rank for the specified tuple by evaluating the specified
>   numeric expression against the tuple. If a numeric expression is
>   specified, the Rank function assigns the same rank to tuples with
>   duplicate values in the set. This assignment of the same rank to
>   duplicate values affects the ranks of subsequent tuples in the set.
>   For example, a set consists of the following tuples, {(a,b), (e,f),
>   (c,d)}. The tuple (a,b) has the same value as the tuple (c,d). If the
>   tuple (a,b) has a rank of 1, then both (a,b) and (c,d) would have a
>   rank of 1. However, the tuple (e,f) would have a rank of 3. There
>   could be no tuple in this set with a rank of 2. If a numeric
>   expression is not specified, the Rank function returns the one-based
>   ordinal position of the specified tuple. The Rank function does not
>   order the set.

In the following script if two people are tied second for the highest salary I get the following salary ranks:

1
2
2
4

What I'd like to do is use the number of years in service to decide which of the tied people has the higher rank. Is this possible?

```
WITH 
    SET [OrderedPeople] AS 
        ORDER(
            NONEMPTY(
                [PeopleDimension].[PeopleHier].[NamesLevel].members,
                { //following means if one or the other is null 
                  //then the row is not excluded
                [Measures].[Salary],
                [Measures].[NumYearsService]
                }
            ),
            [Measures].[Salary]
            *
            [Measures].[NumYearsService]
            , 
            BDESC
            )
    MEMBER [Measures].[Salary_Rank] AS 
        RANK([PeopleDimension].[PeopleHier].CurrentMember,
            [OrderedPeople],
            [Measures].[Salary] //<<<how do I use numYearsService to decide ties?
            )
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY 
        { 
        [Measures].[NumYearsService],       
        [Measures].[Salary],
        [Measures].[Salary_Rank]             
        }
    ON COLUMNS,

    NON EMPTY 
        [OrderedPeople]
    ON ROWS  

FROM [ourCube]
WHERE   
    (
    {TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],7)(0):
    TAIL([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],7)(6)}
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the set already ordered, you use `Rank` without the third argument, i. e.

```
RANK([PeopleDimension].[PeopleHier].CurrentMember,
     [OrderedPeople]
)
```

`Rank` returns the position that the first argument has in the set which is the second argument. The third argument is specifically used for the case when you want to have ties getting the same value. If you use the third argument, then for adjacent elements within the set, the third argument is checked, and the return value is the position of the first element within the set that has the same value for the third argument.

To order by several criteria in MDX, nest two orders within each other:

```
ORDER(
   ORDER(
        NONEMPTY(
            [PeopleDimension].[PeopleHier].[NamesLevel].members,
            { //following means if one or the other is null 
              //then the row is not excluded
            [Measures].[Salary],
            [Measures].[NumYearsService]
            }
        ),
        [Measures].[NumYearsService]
        , 
        BDESC
    ),
    [Measures].[Salary],
    BDESC
)
```

AS MDX `Order` is guaranteed to do a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability), when executing the outer sort, then the members that have the same salary do not change their relative order from the first sort, which means they keep being sorted by years in service.

Comment: +1 thanks - thing is though I have both measures included in the `ORDER` set and I want `[Salary_Rank]` to be based on Salary first and then `NumYearsService`. I've used the cross of both in `[OrderedPeople]` to try to avoid losing any people who are in the cube with a value for NumYearsService but no Salary (not the best example but this is a possibility with the actual cube and measures I have)

Comment: maybe I should change the ORDER set - really what I'm trying to achieve with that set is all the names that either have a salary or a numyearsservice or both (with no duplicates in the set)

Comment: @whytheq I added some suggestions with regard to `order` to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Frank - should I even use `ORDER`? All I need is a set that contains all the members of `[PeopleDimension].[PeopleHier].[NamesLevel].members` that have a non-null salary, and all the members that have a non-null NumYearsService.

Comment: If you want to use `Rank` then you have to have the set on which you want to rank ordered, as `Rank` just returns the position of a member in the set, it does not order the set itself.

Comment: can I not use the third parameter of the rank function to tell it what to determine the order of the rank?

Comment: thanks for your help with this Frank - you certainly answered the question. I now know that the following two options are the same: `SORT followed by RANK(with 2 params)` or `RANK(with 3 params)`. Although my question is now throwing up other questions - best to save them for seperate question/answers (we need more `MDX` on `SO`)